# Switch-Hide pictures based on cell values

Tags: image, excel, vba

I am not an expert on VBA, all I know is based on browsing internet, but some simple codes work for me well.

I am switching pictures based on P52 value, that works perfectly, but then I want to swich different pictures based on cell value P117 and that part of the code does not really work for me. What am I missing in the code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Target.Address <> "$P$52" Then Exit Sub
    With ActiveSheet
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Horizontal - feet"
                .Pictures("B3A").Visible = True
                .Pictures("V1A").Visible = False
                .Pictures("V1AF").Visible = False
            Case "Vertical - simple"
                .Pictures("B3A").Visible = False
                .Pictures("V1A").Visible = True
                .Pictures("V1AF").Visible = False
            Case "Vertical - lantern"
                .Pictures("B3A").Visible = False
                .Pictures("V1A").Visible = False
                .Pictures("V1AF").Visible = True
        End Select
    End With


    If Target.Address <> "$P$117" Then Exit Sub
    With ActiveSheet
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Right"
                .Pictures("3P1").Visible = True
                .Pictures("3P1M").Visible = False
            Case "Left"
                .Pictures("3P1").Visible = False
                .Pictures("3P1M").Visible = True

        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Think through the logic of your if statements causing you to exit the sub.

If the cell is P117, you will hit the first if statement which causes you to exit the sub immediately. So you will never get to your second check.

Embed the logic for each of your operations in if statements like I show here and you will be able to "do something if the cell range is P52 or P117" a bit more appropriately.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'only do the following operation if your cell address is P52 - don't exit out
    'of your entire code if it's not
    If Target.Address = "$P$52" Then
        With ActiveSheet
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case "Horizontal - feet"
                    .Pictures("B3A").Visible = True
                    .Pictures("V1A").Visible = False
                    .Pictures("V1AF").Visible = False
                Case "Vertical - simple"
                    .Pictures("B3A").Visible = False
                    .Pictures("V1A").Visible = True
                    .Pictures("V1AF").Visible = False
                Case "Vertical - lantern"
                    .Pictures("B3A").Visible = False
                    .Pictures("V1A").Visible = False
                    .Pictures("V1AF").Visible = True
            End Select
        End With
    End If

    'you skip to down here if it is NOT P52, which then lets you check again to 
    'see if it's P117
    If Target.Address = "$P$117" Then
        With ActiveSheet
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case "Right"
                    .Pictures("3P1").Visible = True
                    .Pictures("3P1M").Visible = False
                Case "Left"
                    .Pictures("3P1").Visible = False
                    .Pictures("3P1M").Visible = True

            End Select
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

---

If you are going to have a lot of checks like this, you may want to create a `Select case` statement for `Target.Address` too. It's hard to say which is better for you given what you've asked here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. My jet-laged brian does not want to work this morning :-) Btw thanks for the idea of Select case for the Target.address, I will consider it next time. These two cases P52 and P117 will be the only one for this sheet.

Comment: @user3541430 great! If this answers your question, feel free to hit the little checkbox to accept it as an answer - this helps everyone else realize your question is answered.